# Wordpress Plugin for Training Registration

Tags: wordpress

We offer training to people in the Civil Engineering field and we would like to allow people to sign up for a training course via our website, thus we require a WordPress plugin that allows this.

Any plugins that can achieve this out of the box? Our requirements are:

- Allow rescheduling of courses (rather than having to create a whole new course)
- Allow payment via paypal or invoice
- Group Registration; Allow a HR person to sign up multiple training course attendees. There are plugins that allow this BUT they dont allow the HR person to specify each attendees name, address, dietary requirements, etc. They usually just ask 'How many people will be attending'.
- Only allow logged in users to sign up for a training session
- Customisable event look and email content

The Plugins we have tested but dont meet our requirements are:

- Event Espresso
- Event Manager
- Booking System: http://dopdemo.net/wp/booking-system/
- Booking Calendar: http://wpbookingcalendar.com/demo/

Answer (score 0):

I can only say do not buy Event Espresso! Sooo many big words on their website and such a bad product! It doesn't even work with my WP theme and they don't want to do a refund! Right now I am testing simplybook.me which seems to be a good product.

Comment: -1: Please provide more logical reasoning in your answers to help the original poster. Why is Event Espresso a bad product? What Wordpress Theme did you use? Why didn't it work?

Answer (score 0):

Bookeo.
Bookeo has all of your requirements. I have used each and every item you've listed and I also use it for people signing up for training courses.
It isn't a plugin but I have inserted their widget into my WordPress website without any difficulty and it has been customized to fit my website theme.

Best of luck!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Thanks for your answer, it looks looks helpful, but could be greatly improved by offering further practical advice about inserting the widget you mention, and by adding a link to their website.